# Creating TCP Cient connection to send and receive messages

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am currently busy with developing an application that makes a connection with a server through TCP. I have currently a connection with the server but when I try to send a message to the server my application crashes with an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` error.

EDIT: this crash occurs trough sending a message to the server with the function TCP.sendMessage(), the rest of the code will run correctly inside of an asynctask inside of the doInbackGround, but the function I call to send a message becomes form the activity.

This is my code:

```
package jabo.com.roommapper2.TCP;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class TCPThread extends Thread {
    private TcpClient mTcpClient = null;
    private boolean mRun = true;
    String TAG = "TCPThread";

    @Override
    public void run(){
        new ConnectTask().execute("");
        while (mRun) {

        }
    }

    public void cancel(){
        mRun = false;
    }

    public boolean sendMessage(String message){
        Log.d(TAG, "sendMessage: "+message);
        if(mTcpClient != null){
            mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {

        @Override
        protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {
            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    //publishProgress(message);
                    Log.i("Debug","Input message: " + message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... message){

        }
    }
}
```

the thread becomes started from my controlpage activity:

```
package jabo.com.roommapper2.Screens;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import jabo.com.roommapper2.BT.BTConnectie;
import jabo.com.roommapper2.R;
import jabo.com.roommapper2.TCP.TCPThread;
import jabo.com.roommapper2.TCP.TcpClient;
import jabo.com.roommapper2.extraControls.JoystickView;

public class controlPage extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "controlPage";
    private JoystickView joystick;
    private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    public static BTConnectie BT;
    boolean devicefound = false;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    static Context context;
    static Toast toast;
    TextView roomname;
    private int RUN = 1;
    private int PAUZE = 0;
    private int state = 0;
    TCPThread TCP;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control_page);
        TCP = new TCPThread();
        TCP.start();
        roomname = findViewById(R.id.RoomName);
        //toast
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        this.context =context;
        //BT
        String btdeviceName = "LAPTOP-BOAS";
        //String btdeviceHardwareAddress = "F6:D0:05:15:59:26";
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            //
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        String devices[] = new String[] {};
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
            int i =0;
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                if(deviceName.equalsIgnoreCase(btdeviceName) /*&& deviceHardwareAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(btdeviceHardwareAddress)*/){
                    devicefound = true;
                    try {
                        BT = new BTConnectie(device);
                        BT.start();
                        Log.d("Device","Connected");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){

                    }
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    i++;
                    devicefound = false;
                    Log.d(deviceName,btdeviceName);
                    popup("device not found please connect device first");
                    //devices[i] = deviceName;
                    //Log.d(deviceHardwareAddress,btdeviceHardwareAddress);
                    Log.d("Device","not found");
                }
            }
        }
        if (devicefound == false){
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        }
        //Joystick
        joystick = (JoystickView) findViewById(R.id.joystick);

        joystick.setOnJoystickMoveListener(new JoystickView.OnJoystickMoveListener() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChanged(int angle, int input_power, int direction) {
                int power= input_power;
                byte[] message = new byte[4];
                message[2] = (byte)power;
                message[3]= (byte)'\n';
                switch (direction) {
                    case JoystickView.FRONT:
                        message[1] = 1;
                        break;
                    case JoystickView.FRONT_RIGHT:
                        message[1] = 2;
                        break;
                    case JoystickView.RIGHT:
                        message[1] = 3;
                        break;
                    case JoystickView.RIGHT_BOTTOM:
                        message[1] = 4;
                        break;
                    case JoystickView.BOTTOM:
                        message[1] = 5;
                        break;
                    case JoystickView.BOTTOM_LEFT:
                        message[1] = 6;
                        break;
                    case JoystickView.LEFT:
                        message[1] = 7;
                        break;
                    case JoystickView.LEFT_FRONT:
                        message[1] = 8;
                        break;
                    default:
                        message[1] = 0;
                        break;
                }
                message[0] = (byte)(message.length+16);
                try {
                    if (BTConnectie.mConnectedThread.isAlive()) {
                        BTConnectie.mConnectedThread.write(message);
                    } else {
                        popup("cant send to device");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    popup("cant send to device");
                }
            }
        }, JoystickView.DEFAULT_LOOP_INTERVAL);
    }

    public void start(View v){
        if(state == RUN) {
            if (!roomname.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                state = PAUZE;
                popup("started");
                TCP.sendMessage("Start<LOG>");
            }
            else{
                popup("Please give a room name");
            }
        }
        else{
            popup("stopped");
            state = RUN;
            TCP.sendMessage("Stop<LOG>");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: destroyed");
        TCP.cancel();
        //BT.cancel();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: paused");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: stopped");
    }


    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
            }
        }
    };

    public static void popup(String message){
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        if(toast != null) {
            toast.cancel();
            toast = Toast.makeText(context,message,duration);
            toast.show();
        }
        else {
            toast = Toast.makeText(context,message,duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

my question is how to call properly `TCP.sendMessage()`
this function is called in the start function which will be called when a button is pressed.

The thread calls the TcpClient class which is as follows:

```
package jabo.com.roommapper2.TCP;

import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Description
 *
 * @author Catalin Prata
 *         Date: 2/12/13
 */
public class TcpClient {

    final String TAG = "TcpClient";

    public static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.101.11"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 11000;
    // message to send to the server
    private String mServerMessage;
    // sends message received notifications
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    // while this is true, the server will continue running
    private boolean mRun = false;
    // used to send messages
    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    // used to read messages from the server
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
            mBufferOut.println(message);
            mBufferOut.flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the connection and release the members
     */
    public void stopClient() {
        Log.i("Debug", "stopClient");

        // send mesage that we are closing the connection
        //sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION + "Kazy");

        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.close();
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT), 10000);
            //socket.connect(,30*1000);

            try {
                Log.i("Debug", "inside try catch");
                //sends the message to the server
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                //receives the message which the server sends back
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                // send login name
                //sendMessage(Constants.LOGIN_NAME + PreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserName());
                //sendMessage("Hi");
                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }
                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

I had the connection working on an android device with Android 4.4.2, now I am busy with android 7 and now it stops working, is there an explanation for?

if there are some Dutch words in my code it is because of I live in the Netherlands, so also sorry for my bad English.

thanks in advance

EDIT:

I have solved my problem, I did it with the following method:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TCP.sendMessage(name+"<NAME>");
                        TCP.sendMessage("<RMAP>");
                    }
                }).start();
```

Thanks every one who helped

Comment: obviously you are calling sendMessage on main thread

Comment: I now that i am calling it from a main thread but i dont now how to call it so that it is not on the main thread but also get the values that i want to send from the main thread.

Comment: [I would use HandlerThread](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/eaf75cf244df4d2f2ee6) (<= analyze the logcat output)

Comment: I wil take a look at that thanks

Comment: Yust put your network code in a thread or AsyncTask.

Comment: `The thread calls the TcpClient class `. What do you mean with 'thread'?

Comment: So is this for a bluetooth connection? You should have told that on the first line of your post.

Comment: I mean the TCPThread, in this thread i intialize the TcpClient class

Comment: It is for the TCP connection not for the Bluetooth, Bluetooth works already

Comment: `the rest of the code will run correctly inside of an asynctask inside of the doInbackGround, but the function I call to send a message becomes form the activity.`. So you know how to solve it. Put it in a thread or AsyncTask too.

Comment: If it is not bluetooth than why did you post all that irrelevant bluetooth code? And other irrelevant code. You are supposed to post minimal code. Dont let us dig through your irrelevant code lines.

Comment: So i just make a different thread to call this option, you mean?

Comment: I have fixed it as follows: `new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TCP.sendMessage(name+"<NAME>");
                        TCP.sendMessage("<RMAP>");
                    }
                }).start();`

Comment: Thanks every one who helps

Comment: *I have fixed it as follows: ....*  so you are creating new Thread for every single message to send ... what a wasting of resources ...

Comment: Yeah i create each time i would like to send someting a new thread but for me is it now too much time to rewrite a part of my code, so currently i fix it with this solution but in the future when i finish my prototype i will do it with de code you sended.